# (Following Blender Guru Beginner Tutorial) Duplicating Object causes Object to be covered in Particles

Tags: objects, particles

I am currently on Part 2, Level 2 of the Blender Guru Beginner Tutorial. He said to duplicate the Sprinkle, however when I do so (using Shift + D) my duplicated Sprinkle looks like this.

[image]

My original Sprinkle also has these Particle Settings, which his doesn't seem to have. I don't remember anymore when or how I added them (I'm assuming they appeared when I made them on the frosting), but don't seem to be affecting the original Sprinkle.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Deleting those Particle Settings on my sprinkle fixed the duplication issue. I am assuming I added those settings accidentially somehow without noticing and wasn't actually supposed to do so.

If anyone has a better answer with more insight, though, I appreciate any input.